# CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class stepDefinitions при запуске тестов

Tags: java, selenium, test-automation, cucumber

Прошу помочь разобраться. Ошибка где-то в инициализации страницы, если я верно понимаю. вот код:

```
public class AuthStepDefinitions {

private final AuthPage authPage = new AuthPage();

@When("^user on Auth Page$")
public void onAuthPage() {
    AuthPage.getStartPage();
}
```

etc.

```
public class AuthPage extends TestBase {

private String loginPassrod = "test@test.test";

@FindBy(id = "USER_LOGIN")
private WebElement loginInput;

@FindBy(id = "USER_PASSWORD")
private WebElement userPassword;

@FindBy(className = "btn")
private WebElement btnEntrance;

@FindBy(css = "table.dataTable")
private WebElement table;

@FindBy(css = "a.button-new")
private WebElement create;

@FindBy(className = "sidebar-profile")
private WebElement profile;

public AuthPage() {
    PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(new HtmlElementLocatorFactory(driver)), this);
}
```

etc.

```
public abstract class TestBase {

/**
 * Default timeout for waiting
 */
private static final int ELEMENT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 20;

protected static WebDriver driver;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

public void setup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", BaseProperties.driverDir );
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

protected static void onMainPage() {
    driver.get("хxx");
}
```

etc.

Если я верно понимаю то ошибка начинается где-то здесь
private final AuthPage authPage = new AuthPage();
PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(new HtmlElementLocatorFactory(driver)), this);
    }

Что делать не понимаю.

Еще немного информации которая может помочь - может что-то не так указал в runner
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Инициализировал страницу следующим образом в классе страницы:

```
public AuthPage() {
        super.setup();
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
```

К методу setup() добавил аннотацию @Before

Обновил полностью все зависимости в pom.xml
Проблема т.о. решилась